# SQL query to find the count of specific field(Customer_ID)

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-server-2016

I want to find out the count of Customer_ID:

**Issue1:** Below is the code to find the count of `Customer_ID`.
I have 36 million records in my database. When I input the below query to find the count of `Customer_ID`, it's taking too long time to RUN and finally I am getting below error message.

> [Microsoft] SQL Server Native Client 11.0,SQL Server Arithmetic
>   overflow error converting expression to data type int.(8115)

**My Query to find the count of Customer_ID:**

```
SELECT Customer_ID,Count(*)
FROM [Customers]
GROUP BY Customer_ID;
```

**Input Database:**

```
S.no   Customer_ID    Country

 1.        456          INDIA
 2.        789          USA
 3.        1001         UK
 4.        456          AUSTRALIA
 5.        456          SINGAPORE
 6.        789          MALASIYA
 7.        1001         TAIWAN
 8.        1001         JAPAN
 9.        1001         AFRICA
 10.       1001         OMAN
 11.       123          DUBAI
```

**Expected output:**

```
Customer_ID        Count of Customer_ID
      123                1
      456                3
      789                2
      1001               5
```

Please help me to achieve this result. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following two queries and I expect the first query to be much faster, but it isn't. Why?

**Query1**

```
SELECT Customer_ID, SUM(st.row_count) AS [Count of Customer_ID] 
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats st
WHERE object_name(object_id) = 'Customers' 
GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

**Query2**

```
SELECT Customer_ID, COUNT(*) AS [Count of Customer_ID]
FROM [Customers] WITH (NOLOCK)
GROUP BY Customer_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

36 million rows should not be causing an overflow error.  You can try:

```
SELECT Customer_ID, Count_Big(*)
FROM [Customers]
GROUP BY Customer_ID;
```

But that should not be necessary because your table should not result in an overflow (unless "million" really means "billion" in US English).

For performance, you may want an index on `Customers(Customer_ID)`.  It seems likely that you have that, if `Customer_Id` is the primary key of the table.  Of course, if it is the primary key, then the count will always be "1", so the query is unnecessary.